# Refreshing the current route redirects to parent route instead in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-resolver

I have Angular 5 routs configured as follows:

```
  {path: 'malls', component: MallsComponent},
  {
    path: 'malls/new', component: MallEditComponent,
    resolve: {body: MallResolve}
  },
  {
    path: 'malls/:id', component: MallEditComponent,
    resolve: {body: MallResolve}
  },
  {
    path: 'malls/:mallId/point-sales', component: MallPointSalesComponent,
  }
```

I have a code for reloading current page on change some filter/paging/order params which looks like:

```
private changeFilterRoute() {
  let queryParams = {
    'sorter.sortOrder': this.sort.active,
    'sorter.direction': this.sort.direction,
    'page': this.paginator.pageIndex,
    'pageSize': this.paginator.pageSize
  };

  this.router.navigate(this.route.snapshot.url, {
    queryParams: queryParams
  })
}
```

The method *changeFilterRoute()* invoked each time the paging or filtering parameter changed, and it is supposed to reload current page. But instead of reloading current page it redirects user to parent path.

For example I'm on the route

> malls/{:mallId}/point-sales

Where mallId is just a number. Then I change any of paging/filtering params, the method *changeFilterRoute()* invoked, and accidentally the method redirects me to it's parent route:

> malls/:id

with *MallResolve* processing.
Please help me to understand what I did wrong?

Comment: you haven't specified mallId in your query parameters

Comment: actually mallId is fine, it is specified when program run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in invoking `router.navigate`
You should extract path strings from urlSegments from `route.snapshot.url` like this

```
this.router.navigate(this.route.snapshot.url.map(urlSegment => urlSegment.path), {
    queryParams: queryParams
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 constructor(public router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,) {}
 ...

 this.router.navigate(['.'], {queryParams: queryParams,  relativeTo: this.route});
```